How do I type hint for class wrapper or class with method assigned elsewhere than definition in Python3?
In some cases, it is required to inject the same method to multiple classes. To avoid repeated code, I can use a class decorator or class wrapper to assign new attributes and methods to specific class. (Since type hint for wrapper and decorator are the same, I will take decorator as example)
class Base:
    pass

# decorator
def decorator(cls: Input_Type) -> Output_Type:
    def new_method(self):
        pass
    cls.new_method = new_method
    return cls

# wrapper
def wrapper(cls: Input_Type) -> Output_Type:
    class WrappedClass(cls):
        def new_method(self):
            pass
    return WrappedClass

Moreover, for convenience and better maintainability, I want to add type hint for this decorator/wrapper (Output_Type in code block). By type hint, IDE should be able to achieve static analysis and hinting for both original class attr and newly injected attr. How should I do the type hint?
Versions
python==3.8.10
VScode==1.91.1
# VScode Extensions
Pylance==v2024.7.1
Python-Type-Hint==v1.5.1

Return original type
I've tried typing.TypeVar, like
import typing as t
T = t.TypeVar("T", bound=t.Type)

def func(cls: T) -> T:
    ...

However, in this way, the return type is exactly the same as input type, and newly assigned methods won't be hinted.
Using Inheritance
I've also tried using inheritance from typing.Generic and defining a Protocol class, like
import typing as t
T = t.TypeVar("T", bound=t.Type)

class Injected(t.Generic[T]):
    def new_method(self): ...

def func(cls: T) -> Injected[T]:
    ...

But in this way, IDE doesn't hint anything, neither new method nor the originals.
I wonder if there is a way to attach new methods to an existing type(class) in type hint.

This is a common question. The answer you need is intersection types (type[T] & SomeProtocol), but that is not yet a thing in Python's type system.

this is overengineered. Just do method = Base.method in the class definitions.

@juanpa.arrivillaga The situation is that I have a series of classes that needs to inject exactly the same method. I thought it could possible be better to avoid defining a bunch of subclasses that defines exactly the same new methods.

@InSync Thank you for responding. If this is a new feature for Python to implement, I guess my problem is not solvable at the moment?

@cby120 you don't need to, it's one additional line that doesn't repeat anything, exactly the same as a decorator.

Do you even need new subclasses? cls.method = new_method; return cls.

@chepner Sure, this also works. I need subclass for other reasons. Some methods require certain names to be hooked by torch framework, and I need to wrap some original method and call them in wrapped new methods, which is quite convenient using super(). It might also be possible to implement by renaming original methods.

You don't need a decorator to assign an attribute to a class, or to create a wrapper class. The simplest way to do what you need is simply to assign the method in the class scope. This also has the advantage of working well with static analysis tools.
def method_implementation(self, arg: int) -> set[int]:
    """
    a great docstring
    """
    return set()

class Foo:
    method = method_implementation

class Bar:
    method = method_implementation
    def another_method(self, x:str) -> None:
        print(x)


bar = Bar()
bar.method("foo")

And see, static analysis tools and IDEs will understand it.
Here is mypy catching the correct error:
(py312) Juans-MBP:test juan$ mypy foo.py 
foo.py:17: error: Argument 1 has incompatible type "str"; expected "int"  [arg-type]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)

And IDE intellisense will understand it, at least using pylance with VSCode:



Thank you very much for answering. If I need to call a method from parent class, I guess I can do it in function
def method(self):
    super(self.__class__, self).method()
```, I'll try it.

@cby120 that isn' really correct, and will work if Bar is subclassed, and the method is invoked from a subclass instance.

I've done testing. This is a practical implementation for situations with a few classes to be processed. However, for extremely various classes situation, it would be nice to use a function to iterate over a list. Thank you again for answering my question.
